# Testing async exception in spring boot kotiln and coroutines

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotest

I have a web application with the following method written in kotlin using Spring Boot and Coroutines:

```kotlin
suspend fun runJob(request: JobRequest): String {
    .......
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
       runCatching {
            .......
            someIoService.doSomething()
            .......
        }.onFailure{
            // print the issue and throw runtime exception
        }
    }
    ....
    return ....
}
```

I'm trying to write integration test using @SpringBootTest, runTest and kotest that tests a scenario when someIoService.doSomething() throws an exception:

```kotlin
@Test
fun `when doSomething fails then job fails`() = runTest {
  coEvery{mockSomeIoService.doSomething()} throws RunTimeException()
  webTestClient.post(.......)
  waitForJobToFinish() // poll on job status to either finish or fail
 //assert stuff
}
```

I tried using

```
shouldThrow<RunTimeException>{
  webTestClient.post(.......)
  waitForJobToFinish()
}
```

Also tried `runCatching` inside the test, or `shouldThrowSoftly` instead of `shouldThrow`
but nothing seems to work because it's the async process that throws the exception and not the call to runJob itself.

is there any way I can test that?

edit: I just found out that using `runBlocking` and `runCatching` inside instead of `runTest` works. but I'd like to use runTest

is there a way to achieve the functionality of `runCatching` in `runTest`